# $.get sending 2 requests instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have a script function which makes a get request to the url

```
function openPage(url) {
     $.get(url+" #containerMain", function(data) {
    if (data.indexOf("<html id='loginPage'>") == -1) {
                $("#bodyMainTop").load(url); 
            } else {
                $("#containerMain").replaceWith(data);
            }
        }); 
 }
```

I use this method as

```
<a href="javascript: openPage('url')">Register Customer </a>
```

But instead of making 1 request this code is making 2 requests. It is also visible in the network tab of the browser.I am not able to figure this out. Can anyone provide me some guidance or can point me out the direction in which I can start debug.

Comment: Are you sure you don't make a `double click` when you click on the link ?

Comment: your code worked for me. I think you are somewhere double clicking or you have same code repeated one more time

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ yes sir. I am facing this issue many times as I am reusing this function throughout the application.

Comment: you have 2 ajax you get 2 ajax calls what is the problem?

Comment: @madalinivascu are you talking about $.get() and load()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ajax calls

1.`$.get(url+" #containerMain",`

2.`$("#bodyMainTop").load(url);`

so you get 2 xhr requests

Comment: what happens in case of else? In this case also there are 2 requests.

Comment: you will never reach the else branch man so you will always have 2 ajax request